# How to validate ERB or capture an ERB SyntaxError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, erb

Using Rails 3.2.x and Ruby 1.9.3

Given an mal-formed erb template, how can I do one of the following:

- Validate the template and raise an error if it is bad
- Capture the SyntaxError that ERB throws when I try to get the result of a bad template.

I would think this would work:

```
template = "Hello <%= @planet name %>"
@planet_name = "Earth"

begin
 ERB.new(template,nil).result(binding)
rescue
 Raise StandardError, "Bad Erb template"
end
```

But it does not. Instead I get a SyntaxError from ERB.

Is there a way to capture/validate these errors?

Answer (score 2):

Specifically rescuing SyntaxError turns out to do the trick.

```
begin
 ERB.new(template,nil).result(binding)
rescue SyntaxError
 raise StandardError, "Bad Erb template"
end
```

Comment: A rescue clause with no parameters catches StandardError, and SyntaxError is not a subclass of StandardError. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/SyntaxError.html